# React + React Router with Query + LifeCycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, react-router

New to react and react router. And actually using an older version of react router v0.13.

My question is where is the appropriate time to remove query params on page change?

I have some links to pages using react router Link.  Then while users are on the page I update some query params.  But when the user is going to navigate to a new page - I want to remove n number of params depending on some conditions.

My thought was to do this in componentWillUnmount.  However, when I get to my new page and inside render and even componentDidMount, I have the old params that I just attempted to remove

I can see inside my component in the unMount that they are gone, but then they re-appear inside my next component inside didMount.  Race condition?  Or should I be moving this removal elsewhere?

```
componentWillUnmount: function(args) {
     var page = this.getPathname();
     var query = _.omit(this.getQuery(), args);

     this.replaceWith(page, {}, query);
}
```

Rough code of how I send them to the next page.

```
var query = this.getQuery();

<Link to="pageA" query={query}>Page A</Link>
```

Comment: How do you send the user to the new page?

Comment: `var query = this.getQuery();
<Link to="page A" query={query}>Page A</Link>`

Comment: I think the proper way is to pass the desired query correctly to the new page when the link is clicked. This means that your query logic should reflect the correct values before the last `render` of the page your are leaving.

Comment: I don't disagree - but everything is separated out.  So I have a component that handles the navigation and thus is trying to get props/getQuery().  I was hoping that the removal would be reflected by the time getQuery() was called.

Comment: It can still be separated out - but the `Link` element has to have the proper values. Think of it this way: in the current sense, you're asking a web page to open another web page, and then change the contents of that web page after it has been opened. If that was possible it would be a massive security risk. My random script could open your bank's page and take your username and password.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the explanation.